# Constantes en una estructura

Tags: c++, estructuras

Necesito Implementar una Cola circular de la siguiente forma en c++, pero el siguiente codigo es Java.

```
class ColaCircular{
    private int frente;    //frente cola
    int maximo;            //capacidad cola 
    int n;                 //número elementos
    int []vcola;           //vector Cola

    public ColaCircular(int tamano){
    maximo=tamano;             //define capacidad
    vcola=new int [maximo];    //crea espacio en la cola 
    frente=0;                  //inicio variable frente
    n=0;                       //inicio variable número elementos    
    }     
}
```

Intente usar esto:

```
struct Cola {
    short frente;
    const short Max_Cola;
    short Cant_Clientes;
    int UnaCola[Max_Cola];

    Cola() : Max_Cola(10) {}
};
```

Pero Code::Blocks 16.01 no me lo permite:

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Cola::Max_Cola'|
```

¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo declarando la constante dentro de la estructura?

Comment: Por favor, sustituye la imagen por el código correspondiente. Si la imagen se pierde en el futuro la pregunta no tendrá sentido.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que esto:

```
int UnaCola[Max_Cola];
```

no es algo permitido por el estándar de C++ porque el valor de `Max_Cola` no es conocido en tiempo de compilación (nota que es una variable inicializada en el constructor).

Puedes probar en cambio algo así:

```
struct Cola {
    short frente;
    static const short Max_Cola = 10;
    short Cant_Clientes;
    int UnaCola[Max_Cola];

    Cola() {}
};
```